# ActionMailer - Send email based on date condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails project that I would like to set up email notifications for.  For example, if record X expires in 5 days, send an email to the owner.   I have email notifications set up when new users register but can't figure out how to send email based on a conditional (if x = y, then send email).  Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rake tasks for it. Set it in cron to execute once a day.

Example rake task code you can modify and use:

```
task :send_reminds => :environment do
  Record.all.each do |remind|
    UserMailer.remind_email(record).deliver if record.expires_in(5.days)
  end
end
```

Make new bash script, put it wherever you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /your/path/to/rails/app
rake send_reminds
```

Use `crontab -e` to add your task to crontab. Add this line:

```
0 0 * * * /your/path/to/bash/script
```

It will execute it each day at midnight.

Remember to set chmod +x to the script!

Comment: is cron a gem? I'm pretty new at rails.

Comment: [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is a system daemon, which can execute your commands on certain time. I assume that you are on *NIX system. If you are on Windows, it will be harder to do.

Comment: MacOS but the application is on Heroku.

Comment: [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) is information about scheduled jobs on heroku.