# Design Decision using ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm confused about what design decision I need to make.

I know the fundamental use case of ActionMailer in that you would:

- Create a class inheriting from ActionMaier
- define a method in there of what to send and who to send it to and from who, etc

This is where I deviate and lose understanding.

Typically, you would call the method on your mailer model in the controller of a certain action, for ex-

```
def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
 if @user.save
   MyMailerClass.send_signup_email(@user).deliver
   redirect_to @user
 else
   render :new
 end
end
```

What if for example I want to send an email based on if the user hasn't signed in in X days. I'm sure there are a number of ways to do this but curious of the rails best practice way, as I'm not sure where to look. [This is close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077112/actionmailer-send-email-based-on-date-condition-in-rails) I don't want it to send depending on the time of day just when the certain condition is met.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a cron job that runs periodically to check certain conditions and based on those conditions, send an email. This isn't really too far off from what you do with a standard mailer, except rather than sending it from the controller, you would be sending it from a separate script. I usually write a rake task for this:

```
task :send_reminder_emails => :environment do
  users = User.where('last_login <= ?', 10.days.ago)
  users.each do |user|
    MyMailerClass.reminder(user).deliver
  end
end
```

And you would run it with `rake send_reminder_emails`. There are tons of examples available for how to setup a cron job if you aren't familiar with how to do that.

Comment: I believe this is exactly it, appreciate the attention.

Comment: For this particular simple case, putting the logic in the rake task is clear enough.  For more complicated cases, I'd put the logic into a method that you invoke from rake, and test the method as well.  Timecop works well for testing that the right things would happen at the right times.